# Why do I receive `Could not find or load main class` when running the following code?

Tags: java, classpath

I have the following directory structure:

```
C:\CheckinProject\sources\main\EmailProcessor.java<br/>
                         \compile-and-run.bat<br/>
                 \classes\main\EmailProcessor.class
```

The file EmailProcessor.java contains this:

```
package main;

public class EmailProcessor {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The file compile-and-run.bat contains this:

```
javac -d ..\classes main\EmailProcessor.java 
java -cp ..\classes ..\classes\main\EmailProcessor
```

When I run compile-and-run.bat I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ..\classes\main\EmailProcessor
```

Why can't it find or load my main class???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're specifying `..\classes\EmailProcessor` as if Java wants the stem of a filename. It doesn't - it wants a fully-qualified *class* name. So this should work:

```
java -cp ..\classes main.EmailProcessor
```

Comment: Well I feel a bit sheepish now. This worked. Thank you all :-)

Answer (score 0):

`..\classes\EmailProcessor` is not the name of your class. The name of your class is `main.EmailProcessor`. The `java` executable accepts the qualified class name as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the class to run with its Java name, not its filesystem name. I.e., `java -cp ..\classes main.EmailProcessor`

Answer (score -2):

it is **String[] args** and not String args[]